# how to remove CURL_FILE handle from curl handle?

Tags: php, curl

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, null);` or `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, false);` gives `Warning: curl_setopt(): supplied argument is not a valid File-Handle resource`

There is nowhere said what to do to remove completely reference to file handle. Must I start a completely new curl handle to be clean with this option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php, you should change it to `STDOUT`, which is the default. Or, if you're not interested in the output at all, you could change it to `/dev/null`.

Comment: The problem with `STDOUT` is that it bypasses the output buffer for PHP, meaning you can't catch responses with the help of `ob_start()` and `ob_get_contents()`
Is there a way to clean the set file so output buffering would work as well?